# Проблемы с файлами из репозиториев при выполнении docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tag

При выполнении команды `docker-compose up` постоянно появляется ошибка

```
ERROR: Service 'tbot' failed to build: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(gzip: invalid checksum):
```

Если использовать `docker-compose up --build` , то получаю вот такое

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incor
rect data check'))
```

добавление параметра `--no-cache-dir` ничего не меняет
Система Win10x64
UPD. При этом через PyCharm в venv проекта все эти пакеты ставятся без проблем.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:latest

RUN mkdir /scr
WORKDIR /scr
COPY . /scr
RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres
    restart: always        
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - ".env"

  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  tbot:
    container_name: bot
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
    command: python app.py
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ".env"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычно, все решается просто:
в Dockerfile нужно изменить

```
FROM python:latest
```

на

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
```